# How to deal with two classes using methods from eachother?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependencies

I'm implementing MVC in C#, The controller has a property View to call its methods. My problem is that in the View when the user presses a button i want to notify the controller, in other words i need to access functions of the Controller class from my View. So i added a property Controller inside my View. Now this works, but it feels wrong and tight. What would be the way to go here ? Here's an example source code:

```
class Controller
{
    public void DoSomething() { }

    public void SetView (View v)
    {
        this.view = v;
    }

    private View view;
}

class View
{
    public void SetController(Controller c)
    {
        this.controller = c;
    }


    public void OnButtonPress()
    {
        controller.DoSomething();
    }

    private Controller controller;
}
```

Comment: Create an eventhandler or observable for the button click on the View so the Controller can subscribe to that. That way the view doesn't need to have any dependency on the controller

Answer (score 0):

MVC is built the way it is so that the Controller, Model and View are separated and be easy to modify without one affecting the other

The controller should only have the actual logic while the View is only the presentation to the user

Try adding this to your View(html page):

```
@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "OnButtonPress", "ControllerName",new { @class = "yourButtonClass" })
```

Then add the method to your controller class with any logic you want:

```
class controller
{
    public IActionResult OnButtonPress()
    {
    }
}
```